# "Deep length" of a list

Tags: python, recursion

> A list that contains one or more lists as elements is called a deep
>   list. For example, `[1, [2, 3], 4]` is a deep list.
>
> Write a function `deep_len` that takes a list and returns its deep
>   length. See the doctests for the function's behavior.
>
> **Hint**: you can check if something is a list by using the built-in
>   `type` function. For example,
>
> ```
> >>> type(3) == list
> False
> >>> type([1, 2, 3]) == list
> True
> ```

My solution:

```
def deep_len(lst):
    """Returns the deep length of the list.

    >>> deep_len([1, 2, 3])     # normal list
    3
    >>> x = [1, [2, 3], 4]      # deep list
    >>> deep_len(x)
    4
    >>> x = [[1, [1, 1]], 1, [1, 1]] # deep list
    >>> deep_len(x)
    6
    """
    if not lst:
        return 0
    if type(lst[0]) != list:
        return 1 + deep_len(lst[1:])
    else:
        return deep_len(lst[0]) + deep_len(lst[1:])
```

Can we improve this recursive code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would write that simply:

```
def deep_len(lst):
    """Returns the deep length of the list.

    >>> deep_len([1, 2, 3])     # normal list
    3
    >>> x = [1, [2, 3], 4]      # deep list
    >>> deep_len(x)
    4
    >>> x = [[1, [1, 1]], 1, [1, 1]] # deep list
    >>> deep_len(x)
    6
    """
    return sum(deep_len(el) if isinstance(el, list) else 1 for el in lst)
```

Note that:

1. This doesn't create lots of new lists with slices, so I would expect it to be more efficient;
2. `isinstance` is a much more Pythonic way to check types than `type`, despite what the *"hint"* says, as it handles inheritance better; and
3. There's no need to special-case an empty `lst`, as the result is already zero in that case.

Comment: iterative and recursive approach is mixed here

Comment: @overexchange ...so what?

Comment: In your case depth of the stack frame is shorter, which is better.

Comment: for `lst=  [1, 2, 3]`, How does sum look like? `sum(1, 1, 1)`. This code is not working

Comment: @overexchange given that *this exact example* is in the doctest, which I've run, I can assure you that it **is working**. This simplifies to `sum(1 for _ in [1, 2, 3])`, giving `3`, which is the correct answer.

Comment: why `return sum(deep_len(el) if type(e1) == list else 1 for el in lst)` does not work?

Comment: @overexchange **...because `'e1' != 'el'`?!** Did you read the error message? And, as you've *already been told below*, you should be using `type(el) is list` if you *really* want to do it like that.